# Elasticsearch nested query aggregations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, lucene, nosql

Now that I got it right, could you advise me about improving the performance?

I am trying to implement an aggregator filter in my Ruby on Rails app (which does not matter much). I am querying the elasticsearch with following conditions.

What I need is to filter document with certain conditions, filter them also by nested document condition. I do not need any ranking or scoring/sorting. I just need the aggregation of such a query under the `crawl_page_id`.

Any help is really appreciated.

**here is the mapping of the index:**

```
{:created_at=>{:type=>"date"}, 
 :updated_at=>{:type=>"date"}, 
 :domain_id=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :users=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :new_users=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :sessions=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :pageviews=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :session_duration=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :bounces=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :exits=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :conversion_rate=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :goals=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :assists=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :unique_referrers=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
 :by_traffic_source=>{:type=>"nested", 
   :properties=>{
      :source=>{:type=>"string", :index=>:not_analyzed}, 
      :goals=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
      :pageviews=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
      :assists=>{:type=>"integer"}}}, 
  :by_goals=>{:type=>"nested", 
    :properties=>{
      :id=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
      :goals=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
      :assists=>{:type=>"integer"}}}, 
  :url=>{:type=>"string"}, 
  :timestamp=>{:type=>"date"}, 
  :rdn_url=>{:type=>"string"}, 
  :scheme=>{:type=>"string"}, 
  :host=>{:type=>"string"}, 
  :port=>{:type=>"integer"}, 
  :path=>{:type=>"string"}, 
  :query_string=>{:type=>"string"}, 
  :crawl_page_id=>{:type=>"string"}
}
}
```

This one works for me. Is there any better way (perf. wise) to execute such a query?

```
   {"query"=>
          {"filtered"=>
            {"query"=>{{"match_all"=>{}},
             "filter"=>{
               "bool"=>{
                 "must"=>[
                    {"term"=>{"domain_id"=>7721}}, 
                    {"range"=>{"goals"=>{"gte"=>0}}}
                    "nested"=>{"path"=>"by_traffic_source", 
                        "filter"=>{
                          {"term"=>{"by_traffic_source.source"=>"organic"}}
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]},

               }
              }
            },
         "aggs"=>{"crawl_pages"=>{"terms"=>{"field"=>"crawl_page_id", "size"=>200}}}}
```

Comment: A suggestion, it would help tremendously if you stated in words what your query/aggregation is supposed to be doing instead of making the reader deduce it from your code samples

Comment: What I need is to filter document with certain conditions, filter them also by nested document condition. I do not need any ranking or scoring/sorting. I just need the aggregation of such a query under the crawl_page_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, you probably can't get any better than this.

```
 {"query"=>
          {"filtered"=>
            {"query"=>{{"match_all"=>{}},
             "filter"=>{
               "bool"=>{
                 "must"=>[
                    {"term"=>{"domain_id"=>7721}}, 
                    {"range"=>{"goals"=>{"gte"=>0}}}
                    "nested"=>{"path"=>"by_traffic_source", 
                        "filter"=>{
                          {"term"=>{"by_traffic_source.source"=>"organic"}}
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]},

               }
              }
            },
         "aggs"=>{"crawl_pages"=>{"terms"=>{"field"=>"crawl_page_id", "size"=>200}}}}
```